# Datasets for Apache Mahout

Tags: dataset, mahout, recommendation-engine

I am looking for datasets that can be used for implementing recommendation system usecase of Apache Mahout. I know of only [MovieLens Data Sets](http://www.grouplens.org/node/73) from [GroupLens Research](http://www.grouplens.org/) group.

Anyone knows any other datasets that can be used for recommendation system implementation? I am particularly interested in item-based data sets though other datasets are most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is Sebastian from Mahout.

There is a dataset from a czech dating website available that might be of interest to you: http://www.occamslab.com/petricek/data/

Btw the term item-based refers to a special collaborative filtering approach not to the dataset itself, which is usually in the common form of user-item-rating tripels that most collaborative filtering approaches work with.

We would love to hear from your experimentation results and experiences  (if you wanna share them) on our user mailinglist at user@mahout.apache.org

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I would definitely share my results once done.

Answer (score 3):

While searching for data sets, I found few sites that list publicly available data sets which can used for data mining. Some of these can be used for Mahout too.

[Bixo Labs](http://bixolabs.com/datasets/public-datasets/)

[UCI Datasets](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html)

[KDnuggets](http://www.kdnuggets.com/datasets/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at iPinYou RTB Bidding Data Set 
Quora : http://qr.ae/OrqgM
http://contest.ipinyou.com/data-release.html