# Choosing Data Set for Mahout recommend item based algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, mahout-recommender

I am trying to build a recommender using Mahout on EMR. Most of the examples on the internet is about movie recommendation. 
However I want to build a recommender for another data set. As I read on the internet, the format of data set must be in the order of `USERID, ITEMID, RATING` value and I don't know which data set I should use.

Which data sets are suitable for this case and where I can find them from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datasets for Apache Mahout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490785/datasets-for-apache-mahout)

Comment: So what is your question exactly? You want to build an recommender, take the concept of matrix-like ratings but don't want to use movie-recommendation datasets? Why? It doesn't matter if it's movies or music which are rated. The algorithms are the same (it's basically always matrix-factorization). And if you want to use other data, because it's more like your destination-data, how should we know which data is suitable? You didn't give any information at all.

Comment: @sascha I have followed the tutorial https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1TDK3HHBD4EZL/Building-a-Recommender-with-Apache-Mahout-on-Amazon-Elastic-MapReduce-EMR and now I want to try the mahout command on the tutorial with another data set.